# OpenCV SVM Classifier not working across platform

Tags: python, c++, opencv, svm

Using Python / OpenCV SVM + Local Binary Pattern (uniform into 59 bins) to train images into classes of -1 (class #1) with ~600 dataset and 1 (class #2) with ~250 dataset. There is also a testing/prediction function to test images on saved model file.

On the C++ side, I only have a testing interface which loads the above created model, calculates the LBP (uniform) of the image and runs prediction.

The above code was completed and tested to work uniformly across both languages/platforms. Then I re-trained the model with more data to improve model accuracy and re-ran tests in Python, which worked as expected. With the (updated) model in C++, all test data is being predicted to one class (class #1) while the same test work as expected in Python. I have cross checked that the LBP function is still returning same values in Python and C++.

This is how the SVM file is available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-Y-yF2Ht_XAnhuUD8oXeQYHasNfyEzEz/view?usp=sharing)

**Data passed to predict**

Python ==> 1 is returned

```
hist32=[[145. 0. 3. 4. 1. 1. 7. 3. 3. 14. 26. 0. 4. 12. 16. 9. 2. 3. 8. 24. 14. 3. 1. 5. 11. 13. 2. 1. 0. 3. 0. 9. 39. 9. 0. 1. 4. 14. 17. 3. 0. 0. 9. 32. 7. 1. 1. 25. 3. 0. 0. 10. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 47.]]
```

C++ ==> -1 is returned (should be +1)

```
[2.0318828e-43, 0, 4.2038954e-45, 5.6051939e-45, 1.4012985e-45, 1.4012985e-45, 9.8090893e-45, 4.2038954e-45, 4.2038954e-45, 1.9618179e-44, 3.643376e-44, 0, 5.6051939e-45, 1.6815582e-44, 2.2420775e-44, 1.2611686e-44, 2.8025969e-45, 4.2038954e-45, 1.1210388e-44, 3.3631163e-44, 1.9618179e-44, 4.2038954e-45, 1.4012985e-45, 7.0064923e-45, 1.5414283e-44, 1.821688e-44, 2.8025969e-45, 1.4012985e-45, 0, 4.2038954e-45, 0, 1.2611686e-44, 5.465064e-44, 1.2611686e-44, 0, 1.4012985e-45, 5.6051939e-45, 1.9618179e-44, 2.3822074e-44, 4.2038954e-45, 0, 0, 1.2611686e-44, 4.4841551e-44, 9.8090893e-45, 1.4012985e-45, 1.4012985e-45, 3.5032462e-44, 4.2038954e-45, 0, 0, 1.4012985e-44, 0, 0, 0, 1.4012985e-45, 0, 0, 6.5861028e-44]
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue while re-framing the question.

The issue was to do with data type of hist. Since I was using a lookup and manually computing the histogram, the values with float type would be completely different than with int.

*Before*

```
 lbp = Mat::zeros(1, 59, CV_32F);
 // fill the mat
 lbp = lbp.reshape(1, 1);
```

*now*

```
 lbp = Mat::zeros(59, 1, CV_8U);
 // fill the mat

 lbp.convertTo(lbp, CV_32F);
```